# Excel Pivot Table Count Unique Values

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table like so

```
Field       Count of Field
Value1      1
Value2      4
Value3      6
```

The field that shows the summation of the count shows `11` which is correct but how do I just show the unique values in Field (which is `3` in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the values in the Excel column and subtract 1 for the Pivot header and 1 for the Grand Total (if showing).

[image]